# Cannot use Box iOS SDK 2.0 as an included project in multiple projects

Tags: ios, box-api

I've got multiple projects that need to use the new Box 2.0 iOS SDK.  The instructions for using the SDK say to simply drag the SDK project to one's project.  This is fine until you need to use it in another project and need to have all your projects open in Xcode.  Xcode will open the SDK project in only one project at a time.  This prevents any other open projects from building.

Is there a way to do this?  Or do Box need to do something to the SDK project to be sharable or provide an framework instead?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the SDK for each project. Not only will it work better with Xcode, but it is typical practice along with a version control system such as Git to refer to each external library as a submodule so the project can be cloned fresh and built on any system without special configuration.